# SQL matching a string followed by a number in a range

Tags: sql, pattern-matching

I am attempting to retrieve all entries who's part number is a word followed by a number between 3 and 10. I expect it to look like this:

```
like 'STAIR[3-10]'
```

There are never be any characters before or after. This, however, returns nothing. This is my first time using SQL so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: The answer is heavily dependent on the specific database you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I'm working within an ERP system (epicor) for my job. I'm going to try to find out now.

Comment: If your database doesn't support you can switch to a list of hard-coded values: `col in ('STAIR3','STAIR4','STAIR5','STAIR6','STAIR7','STAIR8','STAIR9','STAIR10')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is certain that only digits can follow the prefix, something like

```
 x LIKE 'STAIR%'
 AND cast(right(x, length(x) - 5) AS integer) BETWEEN 3 AND 10
```

might work in many DBMS. `right(x, n)` takes `n` characters from the right of a string `x`. `length(x)` returns the length of a string `x`. So if you subtract the length of `'STAIR'`, you'll get the string after `'STAIR'`  in `x`. `cast()` casts the type of an expression, here to an integer. If `length()` is an unknown function for your DBMS, try to replace it with `len()`.

If there can follow other characters than digits, at least

```
x LIKE 'STAIR%'
AND right(length(x) - 5) IN ('3', ..., '10')
```

might work.

Or the obvious

```
x IN ('STAIR3', ..., 'STAIR10')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN_NAME,'STAIR[3-9]|STAIR[1]{1}[0]{1}');
```